# Why would a government official boast to a reporter about illegal trips to Chernobyl?

Tags: russian-language, andrey-kurkov, death-and-the-penguin

Related: [What is a State Duma Deputy?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22936/what-is-a-state-duma-deputy)

In *Death and the Penguin*, Viktor interviewed a politician who, among other things, boasted about his trips to Chernobyl (even knowing that he was a reporter). Given that that was [illegal](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/22299/why-would-a-ukrainian-police-officer-speak-broken-ukrainian), would it be normal for a government official to say, or was he just unusually reckless?

Viktor does casually mention purchasing, and the two of them consuming, a bottle of Finnish vodka; did he do that specifically to try to manipulate him into such damaging admissions? (He also admits to, for example, having a mistress who is part of the National Opera).

Comment: I found this chapter in Ukrainian in internet "був комсоргом курсу в університеті... він похвалився своїми поїздками до Чорнобиля. При цьому, схоже, Чорнобиль позитивно вплинув на його потенцію". I don't see why it cannot be that he was several times in Chernobyl in 1986 or later - legally, to participate in rescue (or how to name it?) operations

Comment: @Andra That's a definite possibility - if they were legal trips to participate in rescue or cleanup efforts, that would actually make a lot more sense of why he'd openly brag about it to a reporter.